# generic method in interface

Tags: java, generics

i want to make interface has generic methods this methods take object from class is a parameter this is my interface

```
public interface mDataBase<E>{

public<E extends Class> void Store(E x);

public void Search(E x);

public void Remove(E x);
}
```

when i try to implament this mehtod like that code

```
@Override
public <E extends Customer> void Store(E x) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    try (PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(cusFile, true))) {
        pr.println(x.getName() + "$" + x.getNumber() + "$" + x.getNID() + "$" + x.getEmail() + "$" + x.getComment() + "$" + x.getAdv());
    } catch (IOException n) {
        System.out.println("Error :I cant write File that Stores Customers Information Not Found");
        Logger.getLogger(StoreCustomer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, n);
    }
}
```

the program whant to remove `@Override` to work 
and customer is another  class 
i have a lot of type i will use it with the same interface

Comment: Why does `Store` take its own `E` parameter, completely separate from and unrelated to the `E` parameter of the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface declares a method `public<E extends Class> void Store(E x);` but your implementing class declares a method `public <E extends Customer> void Store(E x)`. They must match, either by making the interface declare

`public <E extends Customer> void Store(E x);`

or the class declare

`public<E extends Class> void Store(E x);`

I am guessing you want the former.

EDIT: 
After comments, I think what you want is:

```
public interface Database<E> {

  public void store(Class<? extends E> clazz, E x);

  public void search(E x);

  public void remove(E x);

}
```

And

```
public class CustomerDatabase implements Database<Customer> {

  @Override
  public void store(Class<? extends Customer> clazz, Customer x) {
    ...
  }

  ...

}
```

Though I am not sure the class dance is necessary. I would just do

```
public void store(E x);
```

And then get the class by doing `x.getClass()`.

Comment: sorry it dose not work i need to declear x as object from customer

Comment: Then use `public <E extends Customer> void Store(E x);` in your interface.

Comment: no my interface will take many types of classes i cant make it all customer

Comment: Seems like you are mixing up your generic definitions. Does E need to extend something? Then it should be declared like that.

Comment: no it just was way to solve this problem but if you have anthor way i will be glade toknew it

Comment: @KeroFawzy I posted what I think you should do.

Comment: when i implamet this method it appear like that public void Store(Class clazz, Object x) {}